# Using PostgreSQL trigger on table that updates field?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Depending on values on 2 fields A and B, I would like a field C to be updated or filled with a specific value.

For example :

```
create or replace function periode() returns trigger as
$BODY$
begin
IF A >= x AND B <= y
THEN insert into C values ('z')
END IF;
RETURN NULL ;
END ;
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_periode ON temp ;
CREATE TRIGGER trg_periode AFTER INSERT or UPDATE on temp
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE periode();
```

It does not work : 'ERROR : column A doesn't exist'. I can't figure out why this message appears.

Maybe there is a better way to create this trigger?

Comment: I'd think this would be better fit at [DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What does the table DDL look like? Where does the 'z' value come from?

Comment: 'z' is a value (varchar) I write between parenthesis ; (what does DDL mean ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a database handy to test this, but I believe you need to specify if you want the new data checked or the old data checked.  Assuming new, try:

```
IF NEW.A >= x AND NEW.B <= y THEN
```

**EDIT**:
Taking a guess on what you're trying to do, let's see if this code will work for you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION periode()
RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  IF NEW.A >= 5 AND NEW.B <= 5 THEN
    NEW.C = ''Z'';
  ELSE
    NEW.C = '''';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_periode ON T;
CREATE TRIGGER trg_periode BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE on T
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE periode();
```

I changed your trigger to before the insert to avoid recursive issues. I renamed `temp` to T because I don't like calling things temp.

Also, I made an assumption of what you want C to be when your values don't match.

A [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/36d5f/1) for this has been made if that helps.

Comment: I tried but it says : "C doesn't exist". I tried with "THEN UPDATE temp set C = 'z' ;" failed too.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am always a bit confused witn before or after trigger. what do you mean by "recursive issue" ?

Comment: @Leehan I get a little nervous making updates with an update because that update will fire the update trigger.  *Insert Yo Dawg meme here*  From the PostgreSQL documentation: It is the trigger programmer's responsibility to avoid infinite recursion in such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that table has following columns

```
a,b,c,x,y,z
```

update statement is something like this

```
update xxx set a = 11, b,=23
```

then if clause should be

```
IF new.A >=new.x AND new.B <=new.y
THEN new.C = new.z
```

Comment: A, B, C are columns. x, y, z are values.